# bind to 2 events at the same time in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

i am making an app with tkinter, a module for GUI programming in python, in which i want a button to react to both mouse click as well as enter key from keyboard. is there a way to do it?

Comment: Normally `space` key can trigger the button command like a mouse click if the button gets the keyboard focus.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind more than one thing to widgets, including buttons, but to specifically bind a key press to a button is oftentimes not a viable solution. The reason is simple. In order for a widget to recognize a key press it has to have focus. Generally, the way a widget obtains focus is via a mouse click or tabbing. You can either click your widget so you can press return (which actually does not work for `Button` widgets) or you can press tab a bunch of times til the button has focus and then press return. This could be as simple as a couple-few tab presses or 1000's of them. It depends on your app and the number of widgets in the tab order.

What you can do, is use `bind_all` to redirect a key press to your click function (as below). Keep in mind, if you have something like a `Text` widget on the screen, and you are typing in it, every time you press return it will "click" your button. Of course, you could simply `unbind` the key press if your `Text` widget has focus and then `bind` it again if it loses focus, but that can become a mess to juggle. Especially if you have a lot of `Text` widgets. About the only way I see you doing this with any sanity is to `bind_all` with an F key (F1, F2, etc) or maybe a combination, like Shift+Return, something that is not a common key press.

```
import tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        tk.Button(self, text="click", command=self.click).pack()
        self.bind_all('<Return>', self.click)
        
    def click(self, event=None):
        if event:
            print('I have been virtually clicked')
        else:
            print('I have been clicked')
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().mainloop()
```

Comment: Normally by pressing `tab` key to shift focus across widgets, not only by mouse click.

Comment: @acw1668 ~ I appended my answer

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can be multiple ways to do it. First, let's get a better understanding of button methods like [`invoke()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.html#Tkinter.Button.invoke-method) which is used to call the callback function passed as the argument to the `command` parameter. So binding `invoke()` method to `<Return>` sequence we can call the callback function using <kbd>return</kbd> key ***if the button has focus***. To get focus to a button we can use tab and a system default border will indicate which widget has focus.

So have a look at this example, here the callback function can be called by clicking the button as well as pressing <kbd>return</kbd> key when the button has focus. To get focus to the button press <kbd>tab</kbd> key and then press <kbd>return</kbd> key.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


def func():
    print('Button is pressed')

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')

b1 = ttk.Button(root, text='Button 1', command=func)
b1.bind('<Return>', lambda e: b1.invoke())
b1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You mean: press tab key * number of widgets - widget with current focus from button in tab order. That can be a whole lot more than 1 time. At what point is it far easier to just click the button?

Comment: @MichaelGuidry: i'm not sure if windows work any different but on a mac the `ttk.button` will get focus if you press on it but with `tk.button` to get the focus you need to press tab key. Sometimes it is easier to just fill a form with a tab key and submit by pressing `enter` or interact with some other button with the keyboard rather than moving over to the mouse to perform a click.

Comment: I think the problem here is context. You are absolutely right about forms, but if he is making an app. Tabbing to the proper button could become silly. It could become flat out ridiculous if his app is a table of 100's of cells comprised of `Label`, `Entry` and `Button`.